# Is there any MIT JSON parser with syntax similar to pugixml?

Tags: c++, xml, json, pugixml

So I need to do JSON documents parsing. I already parse xml documents with [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) and now I need to parse JSON documents with the same\similar rules as XML ones.

Is there an opensourse (MIT or something similar) JSON parser with an API similar to pugixml?

Comment: Have you looked at all the ones listed on http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

try my pugixml style wrapper for vjson (fastest json parser)
http://code.google.com/r/denisovod-pugixmlstyle-vjson-wrapper/

sample use:
http://code.google.com/r/denisovod-pugixmlstyle-vjson-wrapper/source/browse/dom_sample.cpp

Comment: It it me or there's nothing on your links? The guy simply forked the vjson repo without modifying it.

Comment: compare: http://code.google.com/p/vjson/source/browse/main.cpp and http://code.google.com/r/denisovod-pugixmlstyle-vjson-wrapper/source/browse/dom_sample.cpp

Comment: not much was added but document/node types, with pugixml usage style.